# Ajax Won't display in the div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am able to get the results from the query by posting though Ajax but instead of the results displaying in the div tag which is on mainInstructor2.php, it displays it on another page, the one listed in action which is InstructorStudent.php. Any help would be appreciated :)

Here's my HTML:

```
    <p id ="byStudent"> Search all the tutoring sessions by student</p>
        <form id="SearchByStudent" action ="InstructorStudent.php" method="post">
            Student Username <input = "textbox" type="text" name ="studentSearch" id="studentSearch" value="" required />
            <button class ="button" type="submit" name ="seachStudentSubmit" id ="searchStudentSubmit" value="submit"> Submit </button>
        </form>

        <div id ="searchByStudentContainer">
        </div>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
<script>

            $(SearchByStudent).submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var form = $(this).serialize();
                var url = $form.attr('action');

                var posting = $.post( url, { studentSearch: $('input[name="studentSearch"]').val() } );

                posting.done(function(data) {
                    var content = data;
                    $(searchByStudentContainer).html(content);
                });
            });


    </script>
```

Here's my php:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    include_once("Connection.php");

    $studentSearch = $_POST['studentSearch'];

    $sql1 = "SELECT Students.StudentUsername 
            FROM Students
            INNER JOIN CLASS_STUDENT
            ON Students.StudentUsername = CLASS_STUDENT.StudentUsername
            INNER JOIN Class
            ON CLASS_STUDENT.ClassID = Class.ClassID
            INNER JOIN Instructors
            ON Class.InstructorID = Instructors.InstructorID
            WHERE Students.StudentUsername = '$studentSearch'";


    $result1= mysqli_query($link, $sql1);

    $resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);

    $studentSea = $resultarr['StudentUsername'];

    if(!$studentSea) {

       echo "   
        <script>
              alert ('Could not find student on file!');
              window.location ='mainInstructor2.php'
           </script>";
    }
    else {
    $sql2 = "SELECT Students.StudentUsername, CLASS_STUDENT.Year, CLASS_STUDENT.Semester, TUTOR_STUDENT.Date,
    TUTOR_STUDENT.TopicCovered, TUTOR_STUDENT.BeginTime, TUTOR_STUDENT.EndTime, TUTOR_STUDENT.TotalMinutes,
    TUTOR_STUDENT.Categories, TUTOR_STUDENT.TutorUsername
    FROM Students
    INNER JOIN CLASS_STUDENT
    ON Students.StudentUsername = CLASS_STUDENT.StudentUsername
    INNER JOIN TUTOR_STUDENT
    ON CLASS_STUDENT.StudentUsername = TUTOR_STUDENT.StudentUsername
    WHERE Students.StudentUsername = '$studentSearch'";

    $result= mysqli_query($link, $sql2);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0)
            {

                echo " 
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Student Username</th>
                            <th>Year</th>
                            <th>Semester</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Topic Covered</th>
                            <th>Begin Time</th>
                            <th>End Time</th>
                            <th>Total Minutes</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Tutor Username</th>

                        </tr>
                            ";

                            // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                {
                        echo "
                            <tr>
                                <td>".$row["StudentUsername"]. "</td>
                         ";
                         echo "
                                <td>".$row["Year"]. "</td>
                         ";
                         echo "
                                <td>".$row["Semester"]. "</td>
                         ";
                         echo "
                                <td>".$row["Date"]. "</td>
                         ";
                         echo "
                                <td>".$row["TopicCovered"]. "</td>
                         ";
                         echo "
                                <td>".$row["BeginTime"]. "</td>
                         ";
                          echo "
                                <td>".$row["EndTime"]. "</td>
                         ";
                         echo "
                                <td>".$row["TotalMinutes"]. "</td>
                         ";
                          echo "
                                <td>".$row["Categories"]. "</td>
                         ";
                         echo "
                                <td>".$row["TutorUsername"]. "</td>
                         ";

                        echo "</tr>";
                                   }
                        echo "</table>";

                }
            else
                echo "This Student doesn't have any tutoring sessions.";



        mysqli_close($link);
    }

?>
```

Comment: what is $form - is it initialized elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

try this  i think u missed #

```js
posting.done(function(data) {
                    var content = data;
                    $(#searchByStudentContainer).html(content);
                });
```

Comment: Just made that adjustment and it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Check these line:

```
<div id ="searchByStudentContainer"></div>

$(searchByStudentContainer).html(content);
```

searchByStudentContainer is id and you are not using # while referring it.

So change this line:

```
$('#searchByStudentContainer').html(content);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I made that adjustment and it still won't display in the div tag.

Answer (score 0):

> document.getElementById("searchByStudentContainer").innerHTML = content;

you can try this

instead of this

> $(searchByStudentContainer).html(content);

Comment: I think so, because the query results are displaying, just on a different page. When i click submit, instead of displaying the results on the same page as the submit button, it redirects to the page of the action url.